# Java Runnable Out of Memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection, runnable

Bad practices aside...

We implement a Java Thread `Runnable` and in its `run()` have a `while(true)` do some stuff.  First thing inside the `while` is a `try/catch/finally` saying, if anything is caught, sleep and then "exit" (which would continue the while).

If there was an `OutOfMemory` issue outside the thread at a higher level, would the thread just die altogether?  If so, the `try/catch/finally` wouldn't `catch` because the execution of the OOM is outside that scope?

Would the thread be garbage collected or not (it died ungracefully).

TLDR: If a `Runnable` gets `OutOfMemory` does it die and just stop in its tracks, or is that exception thrown within the scope of the execution?

```
run(){
  while(true){
    try {
      stuff
    } catch{  //blah
    } finally{sleep}
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about `OutOfMemory` thrown inside the `try` block or from a different thread?

Comment: @tsolakp looks like thrown out of it in a hibernate thread.  `WARN org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext:389 - HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [10] entries
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-25" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.  Shortly after, I realized the `while` wasn't firing off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown when an allocation fails. Therefore, it is passed up the call chain of the thread which made the allocation attempt. Only `try … catch` blocks encapsulating this invocation chain, resp. the allocation itself may catch it.

There is no direct effect on the JVM’s overall operation nor other threads. Of course, if the reason for throwing an `OutOfMemoryError` is that the JVM is low on memory, there’s a chance that this extraordinary condition itself affects the overall JVM operation or other threads at the same time. E.g., *all* threads attempting an allocation at that time may fail with an error.

As demonstrated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46298757/2711488), multiple threads may encounter the same `OutOfMemoryError` instance if the memory is so low that no individual error instances can be constructed. But this does not mean that thrown errors may slosh over to different threads. There’s still a causal relationship between a failed allocation in a thread and the error being caught within that thread. Or con­cur­ren­cy frameworks may hand over the error instance to an initiating thread if an asynchronous op­era­tion failed.

The only reason for a JVM to automatically exit on an `OutOfMemoryError` is an indirect one; if all non-daemon threads exited in response to an `OutOfMemoryError`, e.g. when not catching it at all, the JVM will exit because that’s the standard behavior when no non-daemon thread is alive.

There are scenarios where an application could recover from a single failed allocation when the JVM is not low on memory in general, e.g. if the failed allocation was extraordinary large (the expression `new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE-8]` requires ~16GiB), if it hits general limitations (`new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` is not supported by HotSpot, even if there’s enough memory), or need special memory rather than ordinary heap space (native buffers, graphics memory or PermGen space in older JVMs).

Answer (score 2):

When an `Error` not an `Exception` ocurs the whole JVM -> all Threads will die in most cases.
If your background thread doesn't uses shared resurces it MAYBE surives but as said its very uncommon.
Ah and if it is an deamon threas it will die instat. 
What do you mean with the try catch final?
You cannot realy catch an error, it is like a bullet:

> an error is catchable, you can try to catch but if its thrown you die.

Answer (score 1):

Homework time again?

An `OutOfMemoryError` is an error, not an exception. You could catch an `Error` -after all, they derive from `Throwable`, as does `Exception`- but it's not a very good idea.

Your thread doesn't die, your entire JVM does. Because there's really no graceful way to recover from an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: It is not necessary for JVM to die on `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Not homework time... debugging production time... *shudder*, hence the "bad practices aside".  Was more for my curiosity.

Comment: It's not production code either. What you've written is pseudo-Java that'll never compile.

Comment: Because I'm going to obfuscate prod code when making an example and keeping it simple to just the relevant information to the question.

Comment: As an interesting counter-poiint, Akka intentionally catches Throwables, including out of memory, to effect a graceful shutdown. In most instances this is possible.

Comment: Can the JVM reover:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058198/can-the-jvm-recover-from-an-outofmemoryerror-without-a-restart

Answer (score 1):

When you catch `OutOfMemoryError` in your while loop everything you allocated(assuming they are only referenced in your loop) up to the point memory error, will be eligible to garbage collection.(this will also be the case without the error)

If a thread dies because of `OutOfMemoryError`, its stack will be destroyed and all the object that are referenced from only that stack will also be eligible to garbage collection.

Even if main thread dies because of `OutOfMemoryError` if you have non-daemon threads alive, the jvm will not die.

`OutOfMemoryError` can have different causes, they are listed here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html

Normally It is advised to clean up and exit when you catch `OutOfMemoryError`.